# how to click the dialog window using chrome extention

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Here is the issue 
I was developing a chrome extension (to use locally) that clicks the input type file using JavaScript:

```
<input type="file" id="myFile">
```

like this

```
 var x = document.getElementById("myFile");
    x.click();
```

And I know that it's impossible to change the value of the input `type =file` programatically even if web-security is disabled within chrome browser. What I want the extension to do is "click inside the dialog window (browse) to select a specified file (image)". If it's not possible either, I hope you programmers provide me with a working way to select a particular file.

Comment: Not possible. You can imagine the security implications of doing something like `.val("c:/path/to/all/my/passwords.txt")`. You could write your extension **and** a separate native windows/OSX application and use [native messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) to have the extension tell the native app to upload a file, but that seems a bit much for what you want

Answer (score 0):

Your extension cannot manipulate dialog UIs.

As such, you cannot decide for the user - for the obvious security reasons spelled out in DelightedD0D's comment.

Comment: I've already know about the security issues on that,  my extension is local and I need it only to automate image uploading to fb post

Comment: You could use [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) to ask an external program to manipulate the dialog UI (or, basically, anything, since it's native code) if you don't care about distributing the extension.